# Found something weird in my _users table. Wondering if hacked or if part of the joomla code might the culprit. And most important how to resolve.

Tags: user, phpmyadmin

I noticed that I couldn't log into the back end or front end of a joomla 3.5.1 installation. After hours of trying to figure it out, I finally went to phpmyadmin and viewed the _users table to reset the admin password. 
What I found was weird. Every username is admin and all the passwords were the exact same string, starting with e4da...! The rest seemed normal. The id and name fields were unique and what I recognized from a backup. 
First I would like to know if this has been seen and reported as searches have turned up no hits. 
Second I am considering the best way to fix is to repair from a backup of the _users table. 
The rest of the site seems fine. The public site is operational and I haven't noticed any issues. 
Third any thoughts as to other tables I might check or what could prevent this from happening again? Also I know that not all my users have tried to log in since seeing this problem. I logged in successfully 2 days ago. thanks

Comment: Did you updated from an earlier version of Joomla to 3.5.1 or was it a clean install? Also, any new plugin installed recently?